# Can't import Tkinter on Manjaro KDE

Tags: linux, tkinter, kde-plasma, manjaro

I'm trying to setup Pycharm on My laptop, with Manjaro KDE installed.
This if my first time using Linux and i'm having trouble getting tkinter to actually import

I've seen other threads with their solutions, and none of them have worked for me. I've tried the following line

sudo pacman -S tk

it installs, but I still get the error message, really not sure what I'm supposed to do here.

Comment: what version of python does Manjaro use on your machine? In python 3+ the package name is `tkinter`, not `Tkinter`.

Comment: I'm using version 3.7.2

Comment: Please show the exact error you are getting.

Comment: show your error output